# .htaccess/apache - "404 error" when trying to silently redirect to a file based on the subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have http://s.example.com. I want http://s.ioixd.example.com to redirect to the folder "/sites/ioixd/" silently, via proxy. So I have this rule in /sites/ in .htaccess (since s.*.example.com redirects to that folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} s\.(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://s.example.com/sites/%1/$1 [L,P]
```

It works normally, with just [L]. The problem comes when I change that to [L,P] (because I want it to be a silent/proxy redirect) and I get this error:

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> *Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at s.ioixd.ioi-xd.net Port 80*

But index.html DOES exist, and when I go to http://s.example.com/sites/ioixd manually, it shows the contents of the index.html file, which is just the word "hey" (for testing). Is this not possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you fix the issue? If not perhaps post the content from the apache access and error logs when you try and make the request

Comment: There's nothing in the access or error logs about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is all over the internet but one crucial detail is never said, which led me to spend a day trying to use .htaccess.

In shell, run

`sudo a2endmod vhost_alias`

Then, in apache.conf, add something like this this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName anything.s.example.com
    ServerAlias s.*.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/example/sites/%2/
</VirtualHost>
```

**You need to add the vhost_alias module, otherwise apache will crash because it doesn't know what to do with the "VirtualDocumentHost" part. .htaccess will not work the way described above**